# Google map not displaying in the page

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Already have my `id="ieatmaps"` to call the `googlemaps.js`.
But some how it is not beeing displayed.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```js
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('ieatmaps'), {
          center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
          zoom: 12,
          styles: [
]

        });
      }
```

```css
.ieatmaps {
    border:0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section id="map">
  <div id="ieatmaps"></div>
      <script src="js/googlemaps.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB-aH4ym18aYYe86IiamWV88X-JrVhFLt8&callback=initMap"
      async defer></script>
</section>
```

Comment: `.ieatmaps`  should be  `#ieatmaps` if you want to change the style of `<div id="ieatmaps">` - you'll also want to think about how you are setting the height of that div ... `height:100%` by itself will result in it being 0px high, unless it's position:absolute or fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#ieatmaps not a class

```js
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('ieatmaps'), {
          center: {lat: 40.674, lng: -73.945},
          zoom: 12,
          styles: [
]

        });
      }
```

```css
#ieatmaps {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<section id="map">
  <div id="ieatmaps"></div>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&key=AIzaSyB-aH4ym18aYYe86IiamWV88X-JrVhFLt8&callback=initMap"
      async defer></script>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use # instead of . for ids in CSS.